# I don't get the idea of potential in a capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, potential, capacitance

First off, what is meant by the potential of the conductors? Also potential difference between the two conductors is a function of distance from either right? Then why does it have an exact value. For example take two conductors having equal and opposite charges and separated by a small distance. Now according to my book, any point between them has the same potential. But, when the point is closer to positive plate, should it not have more affinity towards one than other, there shouldn't also be a point where the potential is zero?? Sorry if this is a dumb question but I really don't get the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The electric potential of a point in space is defined by the mechanical energy that it takes to get a (positive) unit charge to that point. We usually define the potential of an infinitely distant point as zero, and then the movement of our test charge is from infinity to the point for which we want to measure the potential.

In case of a capacitor the conductivity of the plates guarantees that the potential is the same on every point of the surface of the two conductors because there is no electric field component parallel to the surface of a conductor. Since there is no field component parallel to the surface, there is no force on a test charge parallel to the surface, either, which means there is no work to be performed as long as we are moving parallel to the surface.

This means that one can assign a potential to each conductor without talking about the physical coordinates any longer.

Comment: but I meant that why is potential same in every point between the space between the conductors. Also, as V is charge dependent why do the conductors have different values of V when it should be opposite because only variable is charge q and conductors have equal and opposite charge

Comment: @user3500780: The potential is not the same between the plates. For a plate capacitor the potential between the plates is a linear function of the distance from the plates (neglecting the fringe fields). The charge does not have to be the same (but opposite) on the two plates.

Comment: Oh thank you for clearing that up! Also what if the case is the charge is equal and opposite, does V1 and V2 same then??

Comment: If there are different charges sitting on the plates, then the potential is not equal. Imagine moving a positive charge from the outside towards a conductor that is positively charged: it will repel the charge, so you have to perform work against the repelling force. Now do the same experiment for a negatively charged plate. Now the plate will attract the positive charge and not only do you not have to perform work, the attractive force will perform work on you.

Comment: @CuriousOne Should you not add your first comment in answer.

Answer (score 0):

> First off, what is meant by the potential of the conductors?

The "absolute" potential is of no importance in a working capacitor. In fact, it's practically impossible to determine. The potential difference between the plates (or between a plate and some ground/earth plane) is the important factor in the capacitance relationship, $C=qV$.

> Now according to my book, any point between them has the same potential.

Your book (if you have quoted it correctly) is wrong.  The **electric field** magnitude can be considered constant for plate separations which are small compared to the plate size.  The potential difference is then $Ed$, where $d$ is the distance from the plate.